# how does the following parameters affect the peak ( radius ,theta) of the its frequency spectrum?

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab, image-processing

The following is the similar magnified picture to the second image that it indicates the parameter i am going to talk about.
[image]
[image]

Suppose i am going to fourier transform (DFT) of the following picture (on the left).
Each white line has r' = 5, distance between each line ending d = 8 , angle theta = pi/2
Then it results the middle fourier spectrum and the right one is the image that i shift its spectrum to the centre point for better observation.

I find out the peak beside the DC component.

[image]

Then, what i what to know is that question on the third image

[image]

I have calculate other peaks of different r' and theta to compare their relationship but i still don't know how do i exactly tell their relationship.
Anyone who can tell me? Thanks a lot!